# How to show a view in this way on Cocoa Desktop?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, cocoa-sheet

I'm doing an app and I was wondering how can you show a view like this:

[image: dropdownwindow]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be called a sheet. [This](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Sheets/Tasks/UsingCustomSheets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001290-BABFIBIA) guide should walk you through how to do them.

You basically make a `NSWindow` that you would like to use as a sheet, then, when you want to show it, call:

```
[NSApp beginSheet: myCustomSheet modalForWindow: window modalDelegate: self didEndSelector: @selector(didEndSheet:returnCode:contextInfo:) contextInfo: nil];`
```

`myCustomSheet` is obviously your sheet and `window` is the window you want it to appear in. Set `self` as the delegate and implement `didEndSheet:returnCode:contextInfo:`:

```
- (void)didEndSheet:(NSWindow *)sheet returnCode:(NSInteger)returnCode contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
    [sheet orderOut:self];
}
```

Hook up a "close" button on your sheet to an `IBAction` that closes the sheet.

```
- (IBAction)closeMyCustomSheet: (id)sender
{
    [NSApp endSheet:myCustomSheet];
}
```

These sheets don't even need to be folded! XD

Comment: Perfect, but can a sheet be placed a bit more down than the app titlebar?

Comment: No, you will need a separate window for that.

Answer (score 0):

This is so called modal dialog. You can create one by dragging in (or loading from code) the separate NSPanel or NSWindow and display it by using one of `runModal...` methods.